# Begginer problem with class in another file

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace MyFirstProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
        


        }
    }
}
```

**And another class in another file**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rock_Paper_Scissors
{
    internal class ComputerGenerateSign
    {
       public string computer;

        Console.ReadKey()


    }
}
```

Why Visual Studio code have a problem ?>"*Error    IDE1007 The name 'Console.ReadKey' does not exist in the current context*"

Comment: You can't have method call like this directly in class body. It has to be used as field/property assigment or in method of this class

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the downvotes - many SO users will downvote questions they feel are too easy, but we all have to start somewhere. @selvin effectively answered your question, the code should be in the body of a method, not in the body of the class itself.

Comment: ... or baziilion similar question ... This definitely deserves downvote - it's duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Use 'Console.ReadKey();' in the body of a method, That way it will recognize. You didn't write a method inside the 'ComputerGenerateSign' class like the class 'program' has the main method. hope this helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rock_Paper_Scissors
{
    public class ComputerGenerateSign
    {
        public void method1()
        {
            public string computer;

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made function call in class which was not allowed. In class you can define properties, fields and functions.

You need to call that function inside a function body.

**Main.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Rock_Paper_Scissors;


namespace MyFirstProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ComputerGenerateSign obj=new ComputerGenerateSign(); 
            obj.WaitForUserInput(); 
        }
    }
}
```

**And another class in another file**

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Rock_Paper_Scissors
{
    public class ComputerGenerateSign
    {
        public string computer;

        public void WaitForUserInput()
        {           
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```